# Getting count before executing a method in android

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Query mSeenRef = db.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).orderByChild("From").equalTo(MessageRecieverId);
    mSeenRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String keyId = ds.getKey();



                    DatabaseReference mSendersRef = db.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).child(keyId);
                    DatabaseReference mRecieversRef = db.child("Messages").child(MessageRecieverId).child(MessageSenderId).child(keyId);
                    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
                    childUpdates.put("Seen", true);
                    mSendersRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);
                    mRecieversRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);

                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

This method turns a specific child called seen to true in my firebase database... I want to get the count of the number of childs which isnt true yet before turning into true... how can i achieve that... I want to execute a method just before turing it into true so i need the count

Database

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: done @AlexMamo......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know how many items the value of your `Seen` property `true`, please use the following lines of code:

```
Query mSeenRef = db.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId).orderByChild("Seen").equalTo(true);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int count = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(count)); //Will print the number of seen messages
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
mSeenRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

As you can see, you just simply need to count the number of occurrences.

Another approach would be to use `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()` which will return a value of type long, which actually represents the number of children that exist within the dataSnapshot object.

Comment: But i tried this method and also getChildrenCount but both gives the number of total childs inside but i want the number of childs where seen=false only

Comment: Please show the code that produces that behaviour but if you are using a correct reference, it should count only the childs where  `seen=false`, right? Have you tried my solution above? What is the behaviour?

Comment: let me make sure... in ur query why is it Seen.equaTo true?

Comment: It's because that's what you've asked. Give it a try and tell me if it works

Comment: Its still fetching all the data inside sendersid and recievers id

Comment: i want to fetch all the data inside where seen=false

Comment: like in the image there are some child with seen = true and some seen=false and i want to fetch count of only the ones of seen = false

Comment: In this case you should use another query in which you should pass to the equalTo method instead of true, false. In this case you'll get all child seen=false. Is it ok now?

Comment: i didnt quite get u... so what query should i add?

Comment: The same query as in my answer but instead of using true, use false, to get all children with seen=false. Is it working?

Comment: Is there everything alright, have you solved the issue?

Comment: No i tried both with true and false multiple times but didnt work

Comment: Why you say it didn't work? What is the behaviour? Do you have an error or what?

Comment: No error but its just fetching the count of the all the childs instead of just the child having seen as false

Comment: Ok, let's try it using TeamViewer. Give me your credentials.

Comment: ID = 772 987 936

Comment: Password = 6355